# Broadcast live audio on my website

Tags: webrtc, openwebrtc

I am having a requirement to broadcast live audio on my website. Scenario is
1)  one user will talk/sing in my application and
2)  his followers will have to listen that live audio instantly in the same application.

Can you please suggest me any 3rd party libraries for this? 
Note: I am developing my web application in ASP.Net MVC5.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Towards that goal, if you plan on using WebRTC, you'll need to add media servers that route media around.

Look at [Kurento](https://www.kurento.org/), [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/) or [Janus](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/) for open source alternatives - especially if you plan on adding video support to it.

You can also try using [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) or [FreeSWITCH](https://freeswitch.org/) - these are telephony based solutions but can be re-purposed to use WebRTC and offer a conference call like experience where you mute everyone and have a single speaker "broadcast" his audio to all the rest.